# Python: How to query a dictionary using a variable as a key

Tags: python, django, dictionary

I have a list from a Django model, which can have dict_items with any key, from the model.
E.g. I can have a list with 'country' attribute, or 'name' attribute from the same model using a function.

```
x = dict_items([(<country: US>, 1), (<country: UK>, 1), (<country: Australia>, 2), (<country: Canada>, 1)])
x = dict_items([(<name: John>, 10), (<name: Jane>, 15), (<name: Smith>, 20), (<name: Jess>, 1)])
```

Now, I am trying to build another function to cleanup the keys, basically `(<country: US>, 1)` to `{'key': 'US', 'val': 1}`

```
    def pctTop5 (dict, keyy):
        pList = []
        for (key,value) in dict:
            pdict = {}
            pdict['key'] = key.keyy
            pdict['val'] = value
            pList.append(pdict)
        df = pandas.DataFrame(pList)
        return df
```

However, I am getting the following error:

```
'countryModel' object has no attribute 'keyy'
```

'countryModel' object here is the Django model, which obviously does not have an attribute called 'keyy'.

**What would be the correct way to pass a variable in order to query a dict key?** I need to pass the variable as a key an reuse the function is different views.

I tried searching, but most of the answers are for using variable to create a list of dicts, but couldn't find any to query one.

TIA

Comment: Can you please share your `countryModel`?

Comment: class countryModel(models.Model):
 country = models.CharField(max_length=100)
 continent = models.ForeignKey(continent, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
 created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
 updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
 class Meta:
         ordering = ('country',)
 def __str__(self):
  return self.country

Comment: so how does the `dict` parameter looks like, what is the value for `keyy`?

Comment: countryModel and nameModel are used as Foreign Key in another model.... keyy could be country or name ... In this case countryModel.country

Comment: can you please provide sample input and expected output. Please [edit] the question.

Answer (score 0):

Please edit the question and add your call that generates the error.

I think the problem is how you call a dictionary, instead of `key.keyy` use `key[keyy]`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Everyone!

Someone wrote getattr() for couple of minutes and then deleted it. I tried changing `key.keyy` with `getattr(key, keyy)` and it solved the problem.

Thanks